# Objective-C and Swift interoperability inside framework with module mapping

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, language-interoperability, module-map

### Context

Years ago my company built an Objective-C framework that uses a C library and now we're trying to convert it to Swift. Since we need to use this C++ library, instead of completely eliminating objective-c code from the base we need to maintain the interoperability between these two languages. 
The key thing is that we need to do it in a way that not all interfaces are available to the app using the framework - that's where my problem relies on.

### Attempts

First thing I searched was about how to use a C++ library with Swift, from all that I searched we needed to create a bridge between C++ and Swift using Objective C. So I started to focus on trying to create the interoperability between swift and objective c, whereas the C++ library comes naturally from the existing connection between C++ and Objective-C.

After a thousand of google searches and safari tabs, I discovered that inside an *app* all we needed to do is create a bridging header and we're good to go, not exactly easy nor difficult but kinda toilsome, but inside frameworks we don't have bridging headers, the only way this can achieved are `ModuleMaps`, these guys act like bridging headers encapsulating ObjC frameworks inside modules.

So I tried this and worked! Hurray!

But the problem is: in order to make this work I needed to make my headers public (and my new swift classes public as well). So more searching came along and I found out that are [Private module maps](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#private-module-map-files). 
I tried to recreate one from tutorials like this:

```
framework module MyDeprecatedObjCFramework {
    umbrella header "MyDeprecatedObjCFramework.h"

    export *

    explicit module Private {
         header "Path/To/Private/Header.h"
    }
}
```

but the compiler wasn't regarding the `Private` keyword at the modules' name ending, and I was being able to access it from outside the framework. Setting a name for it wasn't working either (e.g. `MyDeprecatedObjCFrameworkPrivate` or `MyDeprecatedObjCFramework_Private` or `MyDeprecatedObjCFramework-Private` and according to clang documentation the current pattern is `_Private`).

Creating one file apart and setting it as the `Private Module Map` in the build settings didn't work for me either, in this case there were two attempts, first one was like this:

```
module MyDeprecatedObjCFramework_Private {
    header "Path/To/Private/Header.h"
    export *
}
```

In this case, the module couldn't be accessed by anyone, even internally by the framework. In a nutshell it wasn't being copied to the outputted framework inside `Products` Xcode folder. Adding the keyword `framework` before `module` resulted in `include of non-modular header inside framework module`.

I also found out that these clang things weren't stable enough and could break between major versions. From apple itself it doesn't seem to be a [viable workaround](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115190) and the only solution [for this guy](https://forums.swift.org/t/mixing-swift-and-objective-c-in-a-framework-and-private-headers/27787/7) was to create a lint to prevent outer apps to import private headers/swift classes, which seems to me kinda of messy.

### Final question

**Is it possible to create interoperability between objective-c and swift inside a framework? Is this viable? Would it be better to recreate the entire framework from ground up? Or it's better to split it in other swift frameworks?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues but I did not find an ideal solution. To my knowledge you listed all the alternatives.
[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift) is quite clear:

> To use the Objective-C declarations in files in the same framework target as your Swift code, you’ll need to import those files into the Objective-C umbrella header—the master header for your framework. Import your Objective-C files by configuring the umbrella header:

and as you stated even Apple discourages you from using module maps and recommends puting your Objective-C code in a separate target.

**If** you have time, recreating the entire framework from ground up may be the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, at least I have a good valid point to show to our project owners that we will need to hold a release with the full swift conversion. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Good luck with that. ;)